# SEARCH FILTER QUERY IN ORACLE PL/SQL

Tags: search

I have multiple dropdowns, none of the dropdown is mandatory fields, any of the single selection will execute the query. The values are REGION, DIVISION, CITY, SECTOR, CHARGES, STATUS. The first 4 values are dependent to each other, like if we select REGION, DIVISION dropdown will be populated, and same for other Two fields, SECTOR is dependent to CITY, CITY is dependent to DIVISION and DIVISION is dependent to REGION. (REGION > DIVISION > CITY > SECTOR). But the other two fields i.e: CHARGES and STATUS are independent fields. I want to get data based on any condition.
[image]

Basically I need a stored procedure to execute the data.
Here is my Try

create or replace procedure GET_CITY_CHARGES (I_REGION    in varchar2 DEFAULT NULL,
I_DIVISION  in varchar2 DEFAULT NULL,
I_CITY  in varchar2 DEFAULT NULL,
I_SECTOR  in varchar2 DEFAULT NULL,
I_CHARGES  in varchar2 DEFAULT NULL,
I_STATUS in varchar2 DEFAULT NULL,
I_CHARGES in varchar2 DEFAULT NULL,
Result_Cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) is
begin

```
IF(I_REGION!=NULL) THEN
  
    IF(I_DIVISION!=NULL) THEN
       
       IF(I_CITY!=NULL) THEN
         
       IF(I_SECTOR!=NULL) THEN
         Open Result_Cursor for
          select ID, Region, Division, Charges, Sector, Status, City from CITYDETAILS t
            where Region = I_REGION
             AND Division = I_DIVISION
             AND City = I_CITY
             AND Sector = I_SECTOR;
               
       ELSE      
        Open Result_Cursor for
          select ID, Region, Division, Charges, Sector, Status, City from CITYDETAILS t
            where Region = I_REGION
             AND Division = I_DIVISION
             AND City = I_CITY;
       END IF;
       
       ELSE
         Open Result_Cursor for
          select ID, Region, Division, Charges, Sector, Status, City from CITYDETAILS t
            where Region = I_REGION
             AND Division = I_DIVISION;
      END IF;
      
      ELSE
         Open Result_Cursor for
          select ID, Region, Division, Charges, Sector, Status, City from CITYDETAILS t
            where Region = I_REGION;
      END IF;
      
   ELSE
     Open Result_Cursor for
          select ID, Region, Division, Charges, Sector, Status, City from CITYDETAILS t;
 END IF;
```

end GET_CITY_CHARGES;